# Tracking memory leak in Cydia

Tags: memory-management, memory-leaks, ios4, cydia

I got my app running on my phone to do some tests since I don't have my mac for the day.
However, I would like to track memory leak. Is there any app in Cydia that allows me to see what's really happening in background ?

Thanks ;)